# how to make spring boot mvc understand observables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rx-java

i want to return `Observable` from spring's mvc controller. it works with `Single`:

```
@GetMapping Object a() {return Single.just(1);}
```

as expected i get `1` when i query the server. but when i do the same with `Observable`:

```
@GetMapping Object a() {return Observable.just(1);}
```

the answer i got is `{}`. spring-mvc doesn't subscribe to returned `Observable` but simply serializes it to json. can spring-mvc understand `Observable` out of the box and i just messed up with some configuration? or do i have to register my custom handlers or install some plugins?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Spring MVC Reactive](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-boot-web-reactive) (but it's not currently released as final version). It works with Reactor AND RxJava. You'll be able to write this sort of controller :

```
 @Test
 class ExampleController {
         @RequestMapping("/hello")
         public Single<String> hello() { return Single.just("world"); }
 }
```

or You can write your own class adapter and transform a `Single` as a Spring `DeferredResult` (see this [example](https://github.com/jmnarloch/rxjava-spring-boot-starter/blob/master/src/main/java/io/jmnarloch/spring/boot/rxjava/mvc/SingleReturnValueHandler.java))

This example cames from an [Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/jmnarloch/rxjava-spring-boot-starter) that you may wants to directly use.

Comment: i don't have problems with `Single`class. it works currently. what i need is `Observable`

Comment: That the same idea. (replace Single by Observable).

Answer (score 0):

There is a return value handler in `spring-cloud-netflix`. Below pom dependencies worked for me.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have tested this with `rx 1.x`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade to the spring-reactive, you can use the `org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult`

```
public class ExampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> hello() {
        DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

        // your observable
        Observable.just("world")
              .subscribe(
                      text -> deferredResult.setResult(
                                    ResponseEntity.accepted()
                                                  .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                                                  .body(text)),
                      error -> deferredResult.setResult(
                                    ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)
                                                  .build()
              );

        return deferredResult;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are on springboot 1.5
and want to return Observable from your restControllers
and avoid this message :
"No converter found for return value of type: class io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap"
you have to add two class

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"PACKAGE CONTROLLER"})
public class DispatcherContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {
        returnValueHandlers.add(new ObservableReturnValueHandler());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ObservableReturnValueHandler implements AsyncHandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean isAsyncReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType) {
        return returnValue != null && supportsReturnType(returnType);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter returnType) {
        return Observable.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                  NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {

        if (returnValue == null) {
            mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
            return;
        }

        final Observable<?> observable = Observable.class.cast(returnValue);
        WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(webRequest)
            .startDeferredResultProcessing(new ObservableAdapter<>(observable), mavContainer);
    }

    public class ObservableAdapter<T> extends DeferredResult<T> {
        public ObservableAdapter(Observable<T> observable) {
            observable.subscribe(this::setResult, this::setErrorResult);
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
 @GetMapping(path = "{idDocument}/ropObs")
    public Observable<DocumentDto> getDocumentRopObs(@PathVariable String idDocument) {

    DocumentDto r = documentService.getDocumentRopInfo(idDocument)
        .map(dtoMapper::documentBusinessToDto)
        .doOnError(error -> {throw new ApiErrorServerError(error.getMessage());})
        .blockingSingle();
        return Observable.just(r);
    }
```

and a better practice

```
@GetMapping(path = "{idDocument}/ropObs2")
    public Observable<DocumentDto> getDocumentRopObs2(@PathVariable String idDocument) {

      return documentService.getDocumentRopInfo(idDocument).map(dtoMapper::documentBusinessToDto);
    }
```